# Octave error on El Capitan, not writable error

Tags: terminal, octave, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to install Octave on my El Capitan Macbook but I'm getting an odd error.

```
OSX-3:~ me$ brew install octave
==> Installing octave from homebrew/science
Error: You must `brew link jpeg libtiff libpng freetype gmp fontconfig gd lua` before homebrew/science/octave can be installed
```

So I do what it told me to do ...

```
OSX-3:~ me$ brew link jpeg libtiff libpng freetype gmp fontconfig gd lua
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d...
Error: Could not symlink include/jconfig.h
/usr/local/include is not writable.
```

I tried "sudo brew" as well, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Due to El Capitan update your `/usr/local` ownership might have been reseted to its default `root:wheel` and are not writable without sudo privileges.

Brew and sudo doesn't work well together as brew is intended to write in folder owned by a non root user.

To fix this you have to chown /usr/local :

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Have a look at this issue on the [homebrew's github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/41665) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look and see what I can find out.